# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Mobile Test Workbench - Instrumentalized iOS App Error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

I’ve got a problem with my instrumentalized iOS App for the Mobile Test Workbench iOS-Client. After adding the necessary environments (IPhone and Android) and building the app with worklight, I wanted to test my app with the Mobile Test Workbench. The instrumentalization with rtwBuildXcode.sh succeeded and the app was uploaded to the simulator (with the script-parameter simu). But when the script uploads the app to the local mobile test workbench instance there is the following error:

**WorkbenchTest: this application is not a supported WorkLight one. Please consider using IBM Rational Test Workbench.**

I’m confused! It’s a Worklight app and the android-test-environment runs well but the ios one doesn’t at all. The only thing I change in the Xcode-Project was the “Bundle Identifier” so I could build the app with the script. The original-app runs on Android and iOS-Simulator! Could somebody help me pls? Thx!

I’m using Worklight 6.0 and Mobile Test Workbench 8.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issuse is exactly what you said you did, you changed in the Xcode-Project was the "Bundle Identifier"

You should not do that with a worklight app, you need to change in the application-descriptor.xml

change the "bundleId" in the iphone section to fit what you need.

```
 <iphone bundleId="com.yourbundleid" version="1.0">
        <worklightSettings include="true"/>
        <security>
            <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
            <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
        </security>
    </iphone>
```

The underline reason (if not interested please skip) is that the script uses the "budnle id", and when you change it ONLY in the native project (in XCode), it does NOT know what you did, and fails.

hope this helps

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you Sir! I thought changing the xcode-project-configuration didn’t affect the worklight-project. It’s good to know that changing the configuration with xcode could possible triggers some problems. I was just wondering because I never had any issues when changing the configuration of android projects.

Answer (score 0):

This message is generated by MTWW when the app under test is not a Worklight app... In your case, it seems to be a Worklight project! (there is a difference between MTWW and RTW, as MTWW is limited to WL app only). 
Its seems that in your case, there is an issue in this verification. Here are some question to identify the issue:

- Do you upgrade your WL project from 5.x to 6.0 ?
- Do you deploy your app first before testing it ?

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for answering me question but Ilan already gave a solution for my problem.