# On uploading instrumented RmotProjectName.zip file, error is displayed in test workbench

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

I am using Mobile test workbench. On uploading instrumented RmotProjectName.zip file I get the following `ProjectName: this application is not a supported IBM MobileFirst Platform one. Please consider using IBM Rational Test Workbench.`

I have added android build and there was no problem, when i add iOS build which has the same code the error is displayed.

Log:

> !ENTRY com.ibm.cic.licensing.common.util 4 0 2016-05-10 12:14:40.142
>   !MESSAGE LicenseCheck returned FALSE!
>
> !ENTRY com.ibm.cic.licensing.common.util 4 0 2016-05-10 12:24:01.840
>   !MESSAGE LicenseCheck returned FALSE!

Comment: What is your Worklight/MobileFirst version? How did you build the iOS environment?

Comment: Version of MobileFirst Platform Studio is v7.1.0 and MobileFirst Platform Test Workbench is v8.7.0.

Comment: Referred the following link: [link] (http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBLQQ_8.7.1/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.moeb.doc/topics/t_test_ios_native_device.html?lang=en).

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449048/ibm-worklight-6-0-mobile-test-workbench-instrumentalized-ios-app-error
This is a similar case

Comment: @dom, I have not changed the "Bundle Identifier" anywhere, i have checked the "Bundle Identifier" it is same in application-descriptor.xml and in XCode project.

Comment: @Idan ,@dom any other solution, please help me...